# Compare the dates, compute the difference between them, postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a date column and a balance column for each user. Every time user makes a transaction, a new row gets added to this table. It could be that the user makes 15 transactions during the day, and no transaction at all during 5 days.

Like this one

```
  date                balance
2017-06-01              95.63
2017-06-01              97.13
2017-06-01              72.14
2017-06-06              45.04
2017-06-08              20.04
2017-06-09              10.63
2017-06-09              -29.37
2017-06-09              -51.35
2017-06-13              -107.55
2017-06-13              -101.35
2017-06-15              -157.55
2017-06-16              -159.55
2017-06-17              -161.55
```

The goal is to select the positive and negative transactions made during the same day, compute their average or min value and to consider it as one transaction.If the next day no transaction has been made, then the amount of the previous day should be used.

it means for each day in a month i should calculate an interest and it the balance has not been updated then the balance of the previous day should be used.
Hypothetically my table should look like

```
date    balance
1/6/2017    72.14
6/2/2017    72.14
6/3/2017    72.14
6/4/2017    72.14
6/5/2017    72.14
6/6/2017    45.04
7/6/2017    45.04
8/6/2017    20.04
9/6/2017    -51.35
10/6/2017   -51.35
11/6/2017   -51.35
12/6/2017   -51.35
13/06/2017  -107.55
14/06/2017  -107.55
15/06/2017  -157.55
16/06/2017  -159.55
17/06/2017  -161.55
```

i have added those days that were missing and group the days that were duplicate.

Once I have this done, I can select the number of positive balance days, e.g. 8 days, compute the average positive balance, and multiply it by 0.4%.

```
8*58.8525*0.004=0.23
```

The same should be done with negative balance. but with a different interest rate number of negative balance days, e.g. 9 multiplied by average negative balance during those days and 8.49%.

```
9*-99.90555556*0.00849=-0.848
```

So my expected result is just to have these two columns

```
 Neg        Pos
-0.848     0.23
```

How can I do that it in postgres? The function OVERLAP does not really help since I need to specify the dates.

Besides i do not know how to

1. loop the days and to see if there is a duplicate.
2. See which days are missing and use the previous balance for each of these missing days.

Answer (score 2):

please try this..  replace table with your table name

```
with cte as
(
   Select "date" as date
         ,min(balance) as balance
         ,lead("date")  over(order by "date") next_date
         ,Coalesce(ABS("date" - lead("date")  over(order by "date")),1) date_diff 
from table
   group by "date"
),
cte2 as
(
   Select date_diff*balance as tot_bal , date_diff
   from cte 
   Where balance > 0  
),
cte3 as
(
   Select date_diff*balance as tot_bal , date_diff
   from cte 
   Where balance < 0  
)

Select (sum(cte2.tot_bal) / sum(cte2.date_diff) ) * 0.004 as pos
,(sum(cte3.tot_bal) / sum(cte3.date_diff) ) * 0.00849 as neg
from cte2
     ,cte3;
```